# Problem with 2 request in component(patch usefetch)

Tags: http, nuxt.js, patch, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

i want ipdate current news in my component in nuxt 3. I have 2 request. 1 request: get current news with helpful id.

```
const { id } = useRoute().params;
const {data: newsItem}  = await useFetch('/api/articles/articles/' + id + '/')
```

2 request its submitform with patch request.

```
const submitForm = async () => {
  try {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', title.value);
    formData.append('title_image_full', title_image_full.value);

    const response = await fetch('/api/articles/admin/' + id + '/', {
      method: 'PATCH',
      body: formData,
    });
```

I have problem when i want both display current data and update. I mean my v-model="newsItem.title" display but not update and my v-model="title" update but not display current news. i try to did this `const title = ref(newsItem.title);` but its not work